# Remember a randomly chosen value

Tags: c++

I am creating a game where the user plays against the computer. The computer's name is chosen from an array with five values. I created a random number between 1 & 5 and then use it to choose one of the five names at random. I am attempting to save that name as a function so that I can continue to reuse the value throughout the game.

So far I have successfully gotten the program to randomly select a name for the computer but when I call the function it spits out numbers instead of a string. The numbers are the same though so I believe it is "remembering" the value correctly but it is not displaying it in ASCII text...

Here is my code:
**constants.h**

```
#pragma once
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H

#include <string>

namespace constants {

    std::string computer[5] = { "Duotronics", "Hal", "Shirka", "Skynet", "Icarus" };
}

#endif // !CONSTANTS_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>

#include "constants.h"

void opponent() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int randomIndex = rand() % 5;

    std::string value = constants::computer[randomIndex];

    std::cout << value;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "What is your name?\n";
    std::cin >> x; 

    srand(time(NULL));
    int randomIndex = rand() % 5;

    std::string value = constants::computer[randomIndex];

    std::cout << "Your opponent is the computer " << value << " she is hard to beat.\n";
    std::cout << "Good luck " << x << "!" << '\n';

    std::cout << opponent << '\n';
    std::cout << opponent << '\n';
    std::cout << opponent << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following returned:

```
Your opponent is the computer Duotronics she is hard to beat.
Good luck <user's name>!
00821659
00821659
00821659
```

When I call `value` in main I get the name. However, when I attempt to use the same code in the function `opponent` I get numbers... I am trying to store the randomly selected computer's name as a function so that I can reuse the same name throughout the game. This logic is essential because there are other values in the game that will be randomly selected and I will need the game to remember those as well. Any pointers (pun intended perhaps?) on how to get this working would be very much appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: `std::cout << opponent` prints the address of the funcion `void opponent()`.

Comment: I think you're very confuse. the `opponent` label, in your code, refer to the function that you named `opponent`. But when its compiled a function is placed at a given address in the memory. So when you ask for `opponent` latter in the program, it give you the memory address number, in your case `00821659`. Your code never ever run the code within your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`opponent` return the memory address of the function. You forgot to just call the function and execute its code, and you re-coded it in your main. Also your function should return the name.

This is how you main.cpp should look like :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>

#include "constants.h"

std::string opponent() { // should return string, not void
    srand(time(NULL));
    int randomIndex = rand() % 5;

    std::string value = constants::computer[randomIndex];

    return value; // return the name
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "What is your name?\n";
    std::cin >> x; 

    // you do not need to re code the function here        

    std::string opponent_name = opponent(); // just call it !

    std::cout << "Your opponent is the computer " << opponent_name << " she is hard to beat.\n";
    std::cout << "Good luck " << x << "!" << '\n';

    std::cout << opponent_name << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
Your opponent is the computer Duotronics she is hard to beat.
Good luck <user's name>!
Duotronics
```

Comment: Thank you @Welgriv. I had the function coded in main just to show that it worked.

Comment: I get this error: `E0020 identifier "string" is undefined` However, if I put `std::` in front of string (so it reads `std::string opponent() { <... the rest of the code...> }`) then the error is cleared and the code works. I very much appreciate the guidance to get this sorted out.

Comment: my bad, I failed copy past my code. I edit my post and now its ok.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `opponent()` will not remember `randomIndex`. For this, here I use a `static` version of it. Don't use this in multithreading without proper locking.

```
std::string opponent() {
    static int randomIndex = -1;
    if (randomIndex == -1) {
       srand(time(NULL));
       randomIndex = rand() % 5;
    }
    std::string value = constants::computer[randomIndex];

    return value;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "What is your name?\n";
    std::cin >> x; 

    srand(time(NULL));
    int randomIndex = rand() % 5;

    std::string value = constants::computer[randomIndex];

    std::cout << "Your opponent is the computer " << value << " she is hard to beat.\n";
    std::cout << "Good luck " << x << "!" << '\n';

    std::cout << opponent() << '\n';
    std::cout << opponent() << '\n';
    std::cout << opponent() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @alef. I get this error with your solution: `Warning C6385 - Reading invalid data from 'computer':  the readable size is '140' bytes, but 'randomIndex' bytes may be read.` If I build and run it anyways it returns `▬▼pß↑☺Duo` for the opponent name.